# Elementary question about convergence of power series within a disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I heard the following statement and have been unable to prove it. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers and suppose the following series converges $$\sum a_nz_0^n,$$
where $z_0\in \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$ Then for all $z\in\mathbb C$ satisfying $|z|<|z_0|$, the following series also converges $$\sum a_n z^n.$$

---

I would know how to prove the above if 'converges' were replaced by 'converges absolutely'-- but a bit lost with the above. Many thanks!

Comment: What's stronger? Absolute convergence or convergence?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif I don't see how that's relevant?

Comment: It was a rhetoric question. If you're able to prove the absolute convergence then you would have automatically the convergence of the series simply because $|\sum a_nz^n|\leq \sum |a_n||z^n]$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Please read the question more carefully; absolute convergence would also form part of the assumption.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$\sum a_n z_0^n $ converges $$\implies
\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n z_0^n=0$$

$$\implies (a_nz_0^n) bounded $$
$$\implies |a_n z_0^n|<M $$
thus
$$|a_n z^n|=|a_n z_0^n| |\frac {z}{z_0}|^n $$
$$\le M  | \frac {z}{z_0}|^n$$
and use comparison.

Comment: But doesn't this need absolute convergence of the series in the first place?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif This is known as Abel's Lemma.

Comment: Now it's okay, because before the edit, it wasn't complete

Comment: You don't need the absolute convergence of the series when $|z|<|z_0|$, but you would need it if you also wanted to achieve the same result for $|z|=|z_0|$.